# Limit of a sequence of distributions

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the following sequence of random variables: $x_{k+1} = a + \xi_k\sqrt{x_k}$ where $x_0 = 0$, $\xi_k$ takes values $\pm1$  with equal probability and $a\geq 2$. Does a limiting distirbution for every $a$? If it does, is that a known distribution at least for some special cases of $a$, e.g. $a = 2$?

Comment: Already for $x_4$, the possibility of complex values arises. Are you studying random variables defined over complex numbers?

Comment: As far as I understand, for $a \geq 2$ there should never be a case that $x_k < 0$. Can you elaborate on your example for $x_4$?

Comment: Apologies, a silly calculating mistake, I was wrong.